# Trying to extrude object along the z axis but it extrudes slightly off and won't correct itself

Tags: extrude, blender-osm

I have a map terrain imported. I'm trying to extrude it along the z axis and then create a flat bottom for it. Usually I have no trouble doing this in blender. I select all the faces, extrude, then press s + z + 0 to flatten the bottom plane. However, in this terrain, when I try to extrude it will not extrude nicely along the z axis, instead it extrudes slightly off, and then when I apply my command it ends up slightly shifted.
[image: Object before extrusion]
[image: Extrusion occurring, see that it is crooked]
[image: I've now apply s + z + 0 and it is slightly tilted]

Comment: Try extruding this way - select the vertices, Press E for extrude and without moving the mouse, hit a 'neutral' key. (esc?)
That should release your mouse.  Now drag the Z axis Gismo pointer down.  (check your 'Transformation mode is set to 'Global')

Comment: ...or provide blend file so we can check it out...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Select all faces
- Press E
- **Press ZZ** (yes twice)
- Drag along Z axis
- S + Numpad 0 + Z

Without ZZ:
[image: Z axis is not straight]

With ZZ after E:
[image: Z axis is straight]

After selecting the Extrude tool (or pressing E), press X Y or Z to extrude along a specific axis.
Press it twice XX YY or ZZ to extrude along the "global" axis.