how do i flatten the bottom of a terrain/topgraphy
so i am a 3d printer and i recently started using blender to make some topography but i usually have a base under it thats flat so i need a flat terrain to join to it and i cant figure it out in the photo u can see the hill. i dont want the hill i want it flat so it can go on a base please respond if you know how to do this and if possible send a video
edit: so i have been answered but there are alot of nodes/meshes and it will take a while so im wondering how i only select bottom nodes/meshes

Hi Leo, welcome to BSE. I am sorry, but this site has some strict rules. Of course you can ask questions and as many as you want, but normally for sure you won't get a video tutorial. If you want or need to have that, you should ask on other sites like blenderartists.org. The "normal" answer here will be some text and maybe some images. And i don't know whether you know that, but making a video is much more effort than "just" writing an answer.

select the bottom, then keys S, Z, 0.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123976/plane-to-3d-object/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244230/trying-to-extrude-object-along-the-z-axis-but-it-extrudes-slightly-off-and-wont

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321184/how-do-i-remove-irregular-bumps-on-my-model-and-get-it-3d-printable
