How do I remove irregular bumps on my model and get it 3D printable?
Here you can see like all pins shapes coming out of the side and there everywhere on the bottom and I'm wondering how I remove them while keeping the model completely flat for 3d printing.



Hello and welcome. You can press Numpad 1 and then Alt+Z to toggle into X-Ray mode. Then you can box select all the bottom vertices.

@HarryMcKenzie i tried but it keeps removing to much and i need it completeley flat to 3d print

You see the red areas? https://i.sstatic.net/lGQPmk29.png These are just the visible parts that cannot be printed and I'm sure there are even more non-visible problems in your mesh. So I would say this is not feasible to fix for printing unless you want to go through the hassle to fix these things all manually which is theoretically possible but not worth it. Enable Face Orientation https://i.sstatic.net/26IX1GsM.png Everything has to be blue . No red is allowed to 3D print successfully.

This question is supposed to be off-topic because it lacks focus and requires a lot of manual fixing.
You see the red areas?

These are just the visible parts that cannot be 3D printed because they make the mesh non-manifold, and I'm sure there are even more non-visible problems in your mesh.
There is a simple Make Manifold option under the built-in 3D Print Toolbox which can work on simple non-manifold objects like in the following example, but it does not work for more complex objects like in your case.

So, I would say (though I could be wrong) that your object is probably not feasible to fix for 3D printing unless you want to go through the hassle of fixing these issues manually. This is theoretically possible but may not be worth it.
However, things may not be too grim as there is one quick workaround I know of, though it involves a paid addon. This entails joining another squarish mesh around the model to hide those bumps and using a voxelizer software like Voxility Pro with a very small voxel size, such as 0.01m, so you can get a manifold and 3D-printable result. I rescaled the model to around 15-20 meters in dimension, but it depends on how much detail you need. Also, make sure your mesh has a higher thickness than the voxel size. In your case, I added a Solidify Modifier with a thickness of 0.05m so the 0.01m voxel size will fit and not leave holes in the result. The voxelizer results in a manifold mesh:

Here is a closeup of the result:

The voxels look like pixels:

The resulting blend file is huge due to the high detail. It has around 28 million faces.
Download .blend on Google Drive (2.72 GB)

dude tysm you are a absoloute life saver

Can't be done in Blender because it crashes? Maybe could be split into parts and then voxelized in Blender... Could also be smoothed in the end and decimated probably. The 3D printer probably doesn't print in color so you could save some space removing the color.

@MarkusvonBroady I forgot to mention that it can be done with Remesh (Blocks) modifier as well if no color information was needed. It's important to note though that some 3D printers can print in color. Yeah smoothing and decimating definitely could have been added in this answer but it was so slow I gave up. lol
